# python numpy array from index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 3d array `a = np.arange(108).reshape(6, 6, 3)`.  I want to grab certain indices of the array, as defined by `i = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1]])` such that the result is `[[3, 4, 5], [27, 28, 29], [39, 40, 41]]`.  I need an efficient way to do this, as my actual arrays are significantly larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the first and second dimension indices from `i`, then use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
a[i[:,0], i[:,1], :]   # or a[i[:,0], i[:,1]]

#array([[ 3,  4,  5],
#       [27, 28, 29],
#       [39, 40, 41]])
```